PHP GET JSON request
**Please i'm geting error when try this php json requet to get and show data . i need help
Here is the request:**


ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

 
 $curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://domain/api/customers/2180',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authtoken: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJh'
    ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
 $datas = json_decode($response);

 echo $datas;
 
 
 
 
 



Here is the error :  Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in .....
here is api documentation: https://perfexcrm.themesic.com/apiguide/#api-Customers-GetCustomer
Please help me
**Please i'm geting error when try this php json requet to get and show data

You can't echo a class, as the error message is telling you. What exactly were you expecting to see on the screen?

You are trying to echo a stdClass, you can convert the json result to an array and use print_r to print the array or via it's elements.
$datas = json_decode($response,  true);
print_r($datas);

PHP json_decode documentation

it's work , thanks . god bless . please how to access each data of the result ?

it depends on what the endpoint is sending back. If you do a print_r, you will see all the elements of the array for example:name, then use $datas['name']

please  can you help me to output the json request? follow this link to create an invoice ? here is the link https://perfexcrm.themesic.com/apiguide/#api-Invoices-PostInvoice
